# how to return an empty array when httperror occurs in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am communicating with an API that returns an http error when it can't find results.

For example when sending a get request to /api/fruits/xxxx the API responds with:

```
ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: 'Not Found', url: 'https://limitless-wave-57443.herokuapp.com/https://fruityvice.com/api/fruit/aaa', ok: false, …}
```

I need a way to instead return an empty array which I can use in my front-end to display a "No results found" caption.
I tried using httpError interceptors but I can't figure out how to actually return this array

my interceptor:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request)
      .pipe(
        retry(0),
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          let errorMessage = '';
          if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
            // client-side error
            errorMessage = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
          } else {
            // server-side error
            errorMessage = `Error Status: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
          }
          console.log(errorMessage);
          return throwError(errorMessage);
        })
      )
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `return of([]);` instead of rethrowing the error to just return an empty array instead of an error.